# Snipmatch and Code Recommender plugin does not work together in the Window Builder editor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

after i installed snipmatch plugin to eclipse mars, i could not see code assist proposals in eclipse. i want to see code proposals from code recommenders plugin. it is very usable.

after installed the plugin, it can be seen as below.

[[image]]

after hitting ctrl + space, it can be seen as below.

[[image]]

i could not configure eclipse to see proposals. by the way snipmatch plugin works in eclipse. how can i correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a committer of the Code Recommenders project. This happens because of our change for [Bug 470372](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470372). In order to prevent errors when working with other Java editors, we disable Code Recommenders proposals for editors other than the standard Java Editor.

Since you installed the newest version of Snipmatch, you also updated to the newest version of Code Recommenders, which includes this change.

In your case, you opened the Java File with Window Builder, which includes a Java Editor.

If you open it in the standard Java Editor instead (*Right Click > Open With > Java Editor*) and try content assist, I believe you will see the proposals again.
Another workaround would be to disable Code Recommenders and use the standard JDT proposals. They won't give you proposals with percentages, but at least you'll have them. To do so, go to *Preferences > Code Recommenders > Completions* and uncheck *Enable Code Recommenders code completion*.

I have opened [Bug 474318](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=474318) to track this issue with Code Recommenders and WindowBuilder.

Comment: thanks. you are right, when i open it in the standard Java editor, it works. it does not work with window builder

Comment: We have since then released Code Recommenders 2.2.4, which works in WindowBuilder again. You can install it from our stable update site: http://download.eclipse.org/recommenders/updates/stable

Comment: yes, after this update, i updated eclipse mars, then the problem is fixed. thanks a lot :)